# Run multiple jobs at once and check which one failed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to run multiple jobs at once and need to write which one failed to a log file. How to do it? I tried to point the result to a log file but it's not getting populated.

```
sh test1.sh & test_1_Pid=$!
sh test2.sh & test_2_Pid=$!


wait $test_1_Pid
test_1_Pid=$?
wait $test_2_Pid
test_2_Pid=$?
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your script in a subshell and let each subprocess handle the errors.

```
 (sh test1.sh || echo "test1" >> failure.txt)&
 (sh test2.sh || echo "test2" >> failure.txt)&
```

Or perhaps without a subprocess:

```
 sh test1.sh || echo "test1" >> failure.txt&
 sh test2.sh || echo "test2" >> failure.txt&
```

Demo:

```
touch job1 job2 job4 job5 job7
rm result # when you repeat the demo
for ((j=1; j<8;j++)); do
   (sleep 2; rm job$j 2>/dev/null || echo "job$j failed" >> result)&
done
wait
cat result
```

The result will show the files that you did not create.

```
job3 failed
job6 failed
```